# How to perform "where" query using document ID in Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The is my code :

```js
let newTems = {}
let IDs = ['xyz', 'abc']
let temRef = await db.collection("templates")
```

For each `id` in `IDs`, I am checking if the `id` is equal to the documentID of any document in the "templates" collection and mapping `name` along with `id` to the `newTems`.

```js
IDs.forEach((id, i) => {
  let temSnap = temRef.where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', id).get()
  
  temSnap.forEach(doc => {
    let temData = doc.data()
    
    newTems[i] = {
      id: temData.doc.id,
      name: temData.name,
    }
  })
})
```

I am getting an error saying

```
TypeError: temSnap.forEach is not a function
```

I have tried looking for any syntactical errors but could not find any. Why is this happening?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here. The first one is that you call the `get()` without awaiting it for the `tempSnap` and because that is a `async` call you can't use it in a `forEach` because `forEach` doesn't support `async`.

To resolve your problem you would need first to loop trough the IDs with a `for loop` because that iterator supports `async` calls. And as second use the `await` on the `get()` call.

Your code would look like this:

```js
let newTems = {}
let IDs = ['xyz', 'abc']
let temRef = await db.collection("templates")

for (let i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
  const id = IDs[i];
  let temSnap = await temRef
    .where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "==", id)
    .get();

  temSnap.forEach((doc) => {
    let temData = doc.data();

    newTems[i] = {
      id: temData.doc.id,
      name: temData.name,
    };
  });
}
```